# How can I get back the MS-Jet DB engine?

Tags: ms-access, jet

I have Windows 7 Professional and use a tool to program digital controllers (Trend Controls' System Engineering Tool) that saves its data as mdb files, in the old Microsoft Jet format.

At some point, the tool started to refuse opening the mdb files, considering them and old format. I guess the Jet engine got susbstituted by the newer ACE engine. Erasing and re installing the programming tool does'nt solve the problem.

The only solution i have found is to set up a clean Win XP Virtual Machine in my computer and installing the programming tool there.

Is there a way to get the Jet engine back?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past.  I believe this is what you're looking for.

**Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Note: There is both a 32bit and a 64bit version.